# How to know the number of the current day in the current years using Java?

Tags: java, date, jakarta-ee, calendar

I have to calculate in Java what is the number of the current day in the year.

For example if today is the **1 of January** the resut should be **1**. If it is the **5 of February** the result should be **36**

How can I automatically do it in Java? Exist some class (such as **Calendar**) that natively supports this feature?

Comment: [`java.util.Calendar#DAY_OF_YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. Be careful that month is zero based. So in your case for the first of January it should be:

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 0, 1);
    int dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 5):

With Java 8:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 5);
int dayNum = date.getDayOfYear();
```

Comment: Small point but does that put the first day of the year as zero?

Comment: No January 1st returns 1.

Comment: @assylias mmm maybe mine is a stupid question but can I use LocalDate only into an application server or also in a console application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by console application - but anything that runs on a Java 8 JVM can use that code. If you are on an older version you can use a Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar#get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int dayOfYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.7:

```
int dayOYear = DateTime.now().getDayOfYear();
```

Time zone is crucial in determining a day. The code above uses the JVM's current default time zone. Usually better to specify a time zone.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
int dayOYear = DateTime.now( zone ).getDayOfYear();
```