# Java change row index in matrix 2D

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I try to create a matrix in java that stores a data sets. I want to construct a matrix of 2D, where the row  presents the days of year , and columns presents the hours of day. 
This is my matrix :

```
int [][] dataset = new int [366] [27] ;
```

I want to make the rows  indexed using MyLocalDate.hashcode() instead of int 0 , 1 ... 365 
However, I want to access to my specific data into matrix for example:

```
int data  = dataset [ MyLocalDate.hashcode() ][ 10 ] ;
```

Comment: array won't be a good option here, you should go for `Map`.

Comment: yes, I work of few datasets, is it possible to change arrays index ?

Comment: *is it possible to change arrays index*. Java does not have assoc arrays like php, if you want to use `1000`th index, you will need to define array as `new T[1000]` and your `999` would be of no use. If you want to map `obj.hashcode()` it would be at least `10000000` elements. It does not make sense to create such a big array. You should choose a `Map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code out...it will show the current day number.

Eg: 20 March 2018 --> Day of the year 79.

21 March 2018 --> Day of the year 80.

with this i hope you can get a idea how to tackle your problem.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DayOfYear 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
       int CurrentDayOfYear = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
       System.out.println("Day of Year: " + CurrentDayOfYear);
       Calendar gmtCalendar = 
       Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }
}
```

edit: it seems there are far better ways to do this in java 8.
[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768869/how-to-know-the-number-of-the-current-day-in-the-current-years-using-java)

Comment: Thanks for your help